# TS - why are my class types not compatible with JSON object?

Tags: json, typescript, types, typing

Im working in node.js with typescript and I defined the Tariff and Tariffs classes. I have also fake data created with JSON that should be compatible with the Classes. But I'm getting an error in `resolve()` method that:

> Argument of type '{ blabbla... ' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'Tariffs | PromiseLike'.

```
export class FakeDataProvider implements IDataProvider {

  loadTariffs?(request: LoadTariffsRequest): Promise<Tariffs>{
    return new Promise<Tariffs>((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(fakeTariffs);
    });
  }

}
```

Next I have defined and exported the classes in another file:

```
export class Tariff {
  tariffOptionId: number = 0;
  name: string = '';
}

export class Tariffs {
    // tariff: Tariff = new Tariff(); // this does not work
    tariff: Array<Tariff> = []; // this does not work too
}
```

Then I have exported fake mock-up JSON data in another file:

```
let fakeTariffs =     
  {
    'tariffs': {
      'tariff': [
        { "name": "tariff1", "tariffOptionId": 1 },
        { "name": "tariff2", "tariffOptionId": 2 },
        { "name": "tariff3", "tariffOptionId": 3 }
      ]
    }
  };

export default fakeTariffs;
```

What I'm doing wrong and how could I modify the classes in order to be compatible with fake data?

Comment: Try removing the `'tariffs': {` part of `fakeTariffs`. Try writing `let fakeTariffs: Tariffs`.

Comment: removing the `'tariffs': { ` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `resolve(fakeData.tariffs)` instead of `resolve(fakeData)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have;

```
tarrif
```

in the first part of your code, and;

```
tariff
```

in the JSON...

Comment: Well, thanks! I repaired the typo but it still throws the same error.